# How to use url template with API Blueprint

Tags: apiary.io

I am trying document url template by using Apiary. After following the instruction [urltemplate](https://help.apiary.io/api_101/uri-templates/). It still can not work in the slide instant test.

parameter: question_id
[parameter img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAlqI.png)

```
FORMAT: 1A
HOST: https://polls.apiblueprint.org/

# test

Polls is a simple API allowing consumers to view polls and vote in them.

## Questions Collection [/questions/{question_id}]

+ Parameters
    + question_id (number) - ID of the Question in the form 

### List All Questions [GET]

+ Response 200 (application/json)

        [
            {
                "question": "Favourite programming language?",
                "published_at": "2015-08-05T08:40:51.620Z",
                "url": "/questions/1",
                "choices": [
                    {
                        "choice": "Swift",
                        "votes": 2048,
                        "question_id":1
                    }, {
                        "choice": "Python",
                        "votes": 1024,
                        "question_id":2
                    }, {
                        "choice": "Objective-C",
                        "votes": 512,
                        "question_id":3
                    }, {
                        "choice": "Ruby",
                        "votes": 256,
                        "question_id":4
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

gave vule: 2
Enter call resource got all content. Not get question_id:2 object
[set value img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVsHl.png)
[get result img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLTRf.png)

Anywhere wrong in setting? or I should pay for join the standard?